# Is there a way to check the data in advance of runtime if it's not the correct type?

Tags: c#, data-structures, type-conversion

I occasionally get data that is not completely clean, and during runtime I get error messages because the data doesn't match the expected type.  For example, sometimes the data has a string where there should be an int, or an int where there should be a date.

Is there a way to scan the data first for bad data, so that I can fix it all at once instead of finding out during run-time and fixing it iteratively?

Here's my code which works:

```
class TestScore{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public DateTime Date;
    public DateTime Time;
    public double Score;
}

//read data
var Data = File.ReadLines(FilePath).Select(line => line.Split('\t')).ToArray();

//select data
var query = from x in Data                     
select new { Name = x[3], Age = x[1], Date = x[2], Time = x[5], Score = x[7] };

//create List and put data into List
List<TestScore> Results = new List<TestScore>();

for (int i = 0; i < query.Count; i++)
{
       TestScore TS = new TestScore();

       TS.Name = query[i].Name;
       TS.Age = query[i].Age;
       TS.Date = query[i].Date;
       TS.Time = query[i].Time;
       TS.Score = query[i].Score;

       Results.Add(TS);
}
```

Comment: try using `*someType*.TryParse`

Comment: The above code compiles? It seems to me that TS.Age = query[i].Age should be giving you compile errors....

Comment: You could run a first pass over the data and instead of assignment, you could just test the type of each property. If you find an error, put it into a list and keep going. When you reach the end, the list should contain all errors.

Comment: If you don't want to find out at runtime then you can only otherwise find out at compile time. If the `FilePath` can vary at runtime then you can't really do anything at compile time (because you don't have the files) so you have to do all your validation at runtime. Also you probably want to create your new `TS` inside the loop or you'll be referencing the same one every time...

Comment: @BFree why is that?  I didn't cut & paste the exact code...I re-typed a more generic version so that anyone could understand/see what I'm trying to do.  what error do you see here?  regardless, my actual code works fine/just the way I want it to.

Comment: @Tim Medora Can you show me how you catch the error, or test for the type, and put it into a list and keep going?

Comment: @Chris, `FilePath` can be static and he still might not be able to guarantee the file can be read correctly before runtime. That file may be manipulated before/after different program start-ups. The only way to guarantee the file can be read correctly, is if the file itself is static **and** `FilePath` is static.

Comment: In general you can use `try`/`catch` at runtime to catch errors and attempt to continue. Or, as Daniel A. White suggested, use any applicable `TryParse` methods. Once some unacceptable data is detected it may be pointless to continue, e.g. if you will simply generate additional errors for all subsequent input. If the checks can't be performed at compile time, and you don't want them done at runtime, then just carefully inspect all of the data "by hand" before running the application. Sometimes it is worth having a separate validation application that just checks input for errors.

Comment: @HABO this is really helpful thanks.  i think essentially what i want to do is create a data validation function before using/assigning the data to as tim medora has pointed out.  thanks guys, for putting me on the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to scan the data first for bad data, so that I can fix
>   it all at once instead of finding out during run-time and fixing it
>   iteratively?

Scanning *is* a runtime operation. However, it's fairly straightforward to implement a solution that gives you enough information to "fix it all at once".

The following code shows a pattern for validating the file in its entirety, and doesn't attempt to load any data unless it completely succeeds.

If it fails, a collection of all errors encountered is returned.

```
internal sealed class ParseStatus
{
    internal bool IsSuccess;
    internal IReadOnlyList<string> Messages;
}

private ParseStatus Load()
{
    string filePath = "foo";

    var data = File.ReadLines( filePath ).Select( line => line.Split( '\t' ) ).ToArray();
    var results = from x in data
                    select new { Name = x[3], Age = x[1], Date = x[2], Time = x[5], Score = x[7] };

    var errors = new List<string>();
    int row = 0;

    // first pass: look for errors by testing each value
    foreach( var line in results )
    {
        row++;

        int dummy;
        if( !int.TryParse( line.Age, out dummy ) )
        {
            errors.Add( "Age couldn't be parsed as an int on line " + row );
        }

        // etc...use exception-free checks on each property
    }

    if( errors.Count > 0 )
    {
        // quit, and return errors list
        return new ParseStatus { IsSuccess = false, Messages = errors };
    }

    // otherwise, it is safe to load all rows

    // TODO: second pass: load the data

    return new ParseStatus { IsSuccess = true };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, trying this out now.  This concept is new to me, but yes, essentially what I really want to do is DATA VALIDATION.  I just didn't know what I wanted to do until you brought up the concept.  Thanks Tim.

Answer (score 2):

For **not finding out the errors during run-time**, the best thing that I can think of would be **to correct the data manually** before your program runs ..

But as we are trying do things constructive, I think that using a **static readonly field** to indicate the data error would be helpful. The following is a simple example which doesn't take the failed items, you might want to modify it when you are going to do some advanced handling.

```
public partial class TestScore {
    public static TestScore Parse(String plainText) {
        var strings=plainText.Split('\t');
        var result=new TestScore();

        if(
            strings.Length<5
            ||
            !double.TryParse(strings[4], out result.Score)
            ||
            !DateTime.TryParse(strings[3], out result.Time)
            ||
            !DateTime.TryParse(strings[2], out result.Date)
            ||
            !int.TryParse(strings[1], out result.Age)
            )
            return TestScore.Error;

        result.Name=strings[0];
        return result;
    }

    public String Name;
    public int Age;
    public DateTime Date;
    public DateTime Time;
    public double Score;

    public static readonly TestScore Error=new TestScore();
}

public static partial class TestClass {
    public static void TestMethod() {
        var path=@"some tab splitted file";

        var lines=File.ReadAllLines(path);

        var format=""
            +"Name: {0}; Age: {1}; "
            +"Date: {2:yyyy:MM:dd}; Time {3:hh:mm}; "
            +"Score: {4}";

        var list=(
            from line in lines
            where String.Empty!=line
            let result=TestScore.Parse(line)
            where TestScore.Error!=result
            select result).ToList();

        foreach(var item in list) {
            Console.WriteLine(
                format,
                item.Name, item.Age, item.Date, item.Time, item.Score
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ken, I'm working through your example as well.